# Synthesis of phenoxyacetone from phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

How can [phenoxyacetone](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/152021?lang=en&region=US) be synthesized from phenol?

**My Attempt**:

We would first need to deprotonate phenol by addition of NaH in THF and then add bromopropene.

I'm not quite sure where I would go from here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1-phenoxy-2-propanone isn't a correct name. Are you referring to [this](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C579748&Mask=200) compound as your synthesis would seem to imply? Alternatively it could be [this](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/152021?lang=en&region=GB) but I'm not sure how your synthesis would get you there.

Comment: i was referring to this molecule : http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/152021?lang=en&region=CA

Comment: @Nerdingout Asking questions back and forth in the comments prevents anyone else from benefiting from the information.  Please ask a new question rather than turning this into a tutorial! :)  Thanks.

Comment: @Nerdingout I have rolled back your post to include the question again. It was flagged for *unclear what you are asking*. I then noticed, that you did quite a bit of destruction in the past. If you do not what to have any help any more, you can try to delete the question, rather than destroying it. Thank you for your kind understanding.

Comment: Does not even need to be done in DMF, MeCN or acetone would ber perfectly acceptable and easier to work up

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Your suggested method seems excessively complicated. Substitution of chloroacetone with phenol under basic conditions should give O-alkylation in reasonably good yield. The phenol will be deprotonated and the nucleophilic phenoxide ion will then undergo an $S_N2$ reaction with the primary alkyl chloride.